# ImageView not showing project images

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I am a beginner, learning development for Android. I am currently using Android Studio. Here is the issue.

So I added the images in my project and they are clearly visible in the project directory under drawable (I am talking about the ball images e.g. ball1.png). However, I cannot see the image in imageview project images. Please see the first and second image. How to resolve this so that I can add these images in imageview in layout?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

### Update

It is resolved now, the images are now appearing. But, I am not sure how. I would be glad to know what could be the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

IDE need some time to process physical resource file to resource identifier, Press `ctrl + F9`(make project), after that add imageview again.